# What if I have too many documents labelled in -1 cluster in bertopic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I'm generating topics using bertopic on multilingual dataset (mainly Russian and English). I'm reducing the number of topics to 140. After generating topics, I'm analyzing its quality using the coherence score as suggested in this [thread](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/90#issuecomment-820270553). I'm getting a coherence score around 0.7xx trying different hyperparameter settings. After manually checking, most of the topics do make sense and are interesting.

My issue is my dataset contains 196802 posts and out of these posts, 110550 are being labeled as -1 i.e no topic being assigned. More than 50% of posts are being assigned as -1 which is not expected.

Can you please suggest what can I do in such a scenario?

```
umap_models = UMAP(n_neighbors=15, n_components=5, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine', random_state=101)

sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2")

topic_model = BERTopic(umap_model=umap_models, calculate_probabilities=False, 
                       embedding_model=sentence_model, 
                       nr_topics = 140, 
                       min_topic_size=50)
topics, _ = topic_model.fit_transform(posts)

topic_model.get_topic_info()
```

[image]

Kindly advice. Thank you!